# Add custom actionbar in button dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I am currently working on a project which include action bar. Here, i used custom action bar in different style which i want. But Here, i want to dynamically add new button on custom action bar using java class. I have no idea how it's possible? How can i achieve this?

My custom_actionbar.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#1FA8B2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My CustomActionbar.class

```
public class CustomActionbar {
ActionBar actionBar;
public CustomActionbar(final Activity activity,String title) {
    actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    TextView title2 = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
    TextView back = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_back);
    title2.setText(title);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            activity.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of`setCustomView(int)` use `setCustomView(android.view.View)`

Inflate your layout, keep reference, add new views whenever you want.

Comment: here, i want to add new button "update" programmatically. not in xml layout.

Comment: Yes, but you want add it to existing layout. So first you have to use inflataer `mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)` then inflate your view: `mActioBarView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar)` and add new child to mActionBarView